# python-igraph accessing a specific vertex of a graph

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I have created a graph using python-igraph (using python 3.4) and I am trying to access a specific node outdegree using the following line of code:

```
graph.vertex(i).out_degree()
```

I have found this code on stackoverflow and I was hoping that this is going to work but I keep receiving an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'vertex'
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that you are using python 3.4, so probably you need to use the following:

```
graph.vs[i].outdegree()
```

And that's how you access node i from your graph. I also mentioned the new method to get the outdegree.

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver. It worked well for me. Wish there was an online documentation for all this.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/ is the API documentation for the Python interface of igraph. http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html contains a short tutorial.